# Angular Datepicker change dateformat

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

i use the DatePicker from Angular Material and I would like to change the output format to `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Currently it prints the date in the following format: `Wed Nov 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Normal Time)`

How can I do this?

```
datepicker = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);


console.log(this.datepicker.value.toString());
```

Comment: You can use DatePipe in your template to show date in desired format, more on https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: the datepicker value is a Date object, the "to string" method on the Date object prints in that format.  If you want the format to be different, then the reason matters.  If you want to print it on the screen, then the date pipe mentioned above is the correct method, otherwise you might need something else.

Answer (score 8):

`DatePicker` works with date object. When you print on debugging console you will always see the date in full mode. 
If you want that your component shows the date in a specific format, you need to configure the library on the module.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

More information are available on [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To format only the output of a variable, you should use [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

The Data Pipe can be found on the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Basically, on your `component.html`, you have to do:

```
<p>The date is {{ datepicker.value | date:'yyyy/MM/dd' }}</p>
```

This will display the `datapicker.value` formatted as `yyyy/mm/dd`. You have a lot of other options to format your output based on pipes and even create your owns.

---

To format the date on the `.ts` file, you have a couple of options.

1. Use the Date Pipe from Angular.

   1. `import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`
   2. `new DatePipe('en').transform(this.datepicker.value, 'yyyy/MM/dd');`
2. Use [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) (it changes the prototype of `Date` object, adding a `format` method)
3. Use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format)
4. Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) (overkill, super heavy for such small use)

Comment: how can i do this in the .ts file?

Comment: For: "how can i do this in the .ts file?" See: https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

Comment: Personally I would add https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format to the recommendations

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to format your date to "YYYY/MM/DD" format

```
moment(this.datepicker.value).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
```

using moment will help us change date into different formats

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
```

Then,

```
let val = this.dynamicForm.get('datePicker').value;
val = formatDate(val,'yyyy/MM/dd','en');
this.dynamicForm.controls['datePicker'].setValue(val);
```