# DateTime Picker in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

is it possible to get a DateTime picker with this format: "**2019-09-21T12:54:30**". I would be glad if I can get such picker that produces that format. Can bootstrap, momentjs mm... work?
Thanks

Comment: It's already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53124696/angular-datepicker-change-dateformat

Comment: Which UI did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a date from any of the datepickers available in angular and you can use `moment js` to change that respective time to different time formats.

https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/